# Node - trigger cli flags inside the script

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to trigger cli flags from inside a node script that's already been called via cli?

**example**

I want to call

```
$ node chrome-inspect.js
```

and have it run the same as

```
$ node --inspect --debug-brk chrome-inspect.js
```

Is this possible?

*I'm planning to use `exec` to do this unless there is a more seamless way*

Comment: Just to clarify, is `chrome-inspect.js` a file you own?

Comment: @kopiro Yep, it's my script

Comment: try by set `process.argv = ['--inspect', '--debug-brk']` before everything else.

Comment: @kopiro no success. I get the same output as if I just ran the script with no arguments.